# NodeJs with docker unable to run script

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I'm trying to run express.js server in docker container but when I run command "docker-compose up" then I have following error.

```
Recreating node-app ... done
Attaching to node-app
node-app | (node:1) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
node-app | (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node-app | /var/www/app/server.js:1
node-app | import express from "express";
node-app | ^^^^^^
node-app | 
node-app | SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
node-app |     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
node-app |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
node-app |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
node-app |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
node-app |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
node-app |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
node-app |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
node-app | 
node-app | Node.js v18.16.1
node-app | (node:1) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
node-app | (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node-app | /var/www/app/server.js:1
node-app | import express from "express";
node-app | ^^^^^^
node-app | 
node-app | SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
node-app |     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
node-app |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
node-app |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
node-app |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
node-app |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
node-app |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
node-app |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
node-app | 
node-app | Node.js v18.16.1
node-app exited with code 1
```

And second issue. In my project I don't see reflection from "node_modules" installed in container.

This is my file structure:
[image]

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  node:
      build:
          context: ../
          dockerfile: .docker/node/Dockerfile
      container_name: node-app
      restart: always
      ports:
          - '3000:3000'
      volumes:
          - ../:/var/www
      environment:
          PORT: 3000
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.16.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  nano

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY ./app/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./app ./

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

server.js

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server,{allowEIO3: true});
const PORT = 3000;
server.listen(PORT);
console.log("Server is running");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

const connections = [];

io.sockets.on("connection", socket => {
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log(" %s sockets is connected", connections.length);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });

    socket.on("sending message", message => {

        console.log("Message is received :", message);

        io.sockets.emit("new message", { message: message });
    });
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "socketapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "nodemon ./server.js --exec babel-node -e js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "socket.io": "^4.7.0"
    }
}
```

When I change import to require I see a bit different error now:

```
Recreating node-app ... done
Attaching to node-app
node-app | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
node-app |   throw err;
node-app |   ^
node-app | 
node-app | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
node-app | Require stack:
node-app | - /var/www/app/server.js
node-app |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
node-app |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
node-app |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
node-app |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/app/server.js:1:17)
node-app |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
node-app |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
node-app |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
node-app |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
node-app |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
node-app |   requireStack: [ '/var/www/app/server.js' ]
node-app | }
node-app | 
node-app | Node.js v18.16.1
node-app | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
node-app |   throw err;
node-app |   ^
node-app | 
node-app | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
node-app | Require stack:
node-app | - /var/www/app/server.js
node-app |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
node-app |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
node-app |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
node-app |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/app/server.js:1:17)
node-app |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
node-app |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
node-app |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
node-app |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
node-app |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
node-app |   requireStack: [ '/var/www/app/server.js' ]
node-app | }
node-app | 
node-app | Node.js v18.16.1
node-app exited with code 1
node-app | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
node-app |   throw err;
node-app |   ^
node-app | 
node-app | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
node-app | Require stack:
node-app | - /var/www/app/server.js
node-app |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
node-app |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
node-app |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
node-app |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/app/server.js:1:17)
node-app |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
node-app |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
node-app |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
node-app |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
node-app |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
node-app |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
node-app |   requireStack: [ '/var/www/app/server.js' ]
node-app | }
node-app | 
node-app | Node.js v18.16.1
node-app exited with code 1
```

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the content of your package.json file.

Comment: @Klick, I copied all of your code and built the app locally, simplest fix is to change the `import exspress` to `require express` as I mentioned, I hope you get it working! Chow

Comment: @SterbenTheOG I change it but know erroris diferent.

Comment: Your `volumes:` block is hiding absolutely everything in your image, including the source code and the `node_modules` tree.  I'd suggest deleting this block, which is likely to help with the final error.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you. It works now. Do you know maybe answer for my second question? How have a copy node_modules in project not only in container?

Comment: Assuming you don't hide it with a volume mount, the `RUN npm install` line will give you a `node_modules` tree in your image.  In development you can just run `npm install` on your host like normal; make sure to include `node_modules` in a `.dockerignore` file to improve build speed and avoid incompatibilities between the two environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a error, it's in your terminal output: `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`

Try and either convert your project to a module as it suggests or change your nodejs project to be a commonJS project, by changing the `import express from "express";` to `const express = require('express');` in your code and try again.

Please update your post with a snapshot of the `package,json` you are using as someone requested :)

Comment: I replace require to import and now the error is different but still can't run container. Regards

Comment: Hello, please past the terminal output of issues you are getting, I also got some errors after copying the files you posted, but they were wimple errors on my side.

Post any changes you get and I'll help debug if I can :)